# How to get replies of a specific tweet

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to get replies for a specific tweet.

This code helps me to get the last tweet but I can't get user's replies to this tweet.

```
var ctxTwitterContext = new TwitterContext(auth);

var srch = (from search in ctxTwitterContext.Search
            where search.Type == SearchType.Search
               && search.Query == "to:" + "ScreenName" + " OR from:" + "ScreenName"
               && search.Count == 1
            select search).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I replaced the ScreenName with my twitter ScreenName it's a text not a variable .

Comment: Why are you concatenating strings like that? If you have no variables, use a single string, like `"to:ScreenName OR from:ScreenName"`

Comment: it's just a first try and it works it makes me get the tweets from my TimeLine my question is how could i get replies for a specific tweet

Comment: The Twitter API doesn't have an endpoint that returns replies or conversations.

Comment: But i need to get the replies so as to use it in my c# App, is it impossible to retrieve them or is there an other way ?

Comment: Yakhlaf, at least try to read the comment by Joe. This is **not** possible.